# VLC Stuck in playlist mode. I hear audio but no video!

Tags: audio, video, vlc

[image: Screen shot]

My VLC player is stuck in playlist mode, and I can not get it to play the video but I can hear Audio. It doesn't work on any of my videos. But all my quick time files work. My VLC is up to date. It was working earlier today, I made no adjustments then a few hours ago I went to open up a video and I can't get it out of playlist mode to show the video.

Comment: Maybe it's in full-screen mode? When videos are played full-screen, they appear in a separate space from the current desktop.

Comment: No I've tried looking for it already that's not it.

Comment: Exact same problem here - VLC 2.2 on OSX EL Capitan 10.11.4.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Preferences and click reset all.

Comment: Hi Parker, welcome to Ask Different, please provide a small detailed description of the answer to maintain a good quality answer.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me on Mac OS

Answer (score 1):

i had this same issue, i did try docking and undocking also fullscreen toggle but neither worked for me.

my solution: toggle set as desktop background (when set it fixxed) then reverted back to normal and still working again yey!

cause: i hit undock playlist to see what it would do... (broke video, audio working)

vlc 2.2.6 umbrella,
windows 7 64bit (will never "upgrade" to adblasters)

Answer (score 0):

I had some luck (in Windows 10): while it's playing, toggle/untoggle **Playlist**, **Docked Playlist** and **Fullscreen Interface**. Unfortunately, I can't recall the particular order. Try some messing around with those three.